# GCC warning about assigning a pointer variable with an array?

Tags: c, arrays

code snippet:

```
int *c[2] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

gives warning:

```
warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int'
      [-Wint-conversion]
    int *c[2] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
                  ^
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
    int *c[2] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
                    ^
```

I suppose array `{1,2,3}` would decay to pointer so the assignment be legit?

Further more, according to the warning, why does the compiler think i'm trying to assign `int` to `int *`? instead of `int array type` to `int *`?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to initialise `int c[2][3]` with the given data.

Comment: Hi Weather, `c` is a 2-element array of pointers, you can `gcc -S` to check the assembly implementation compared with `int cc[2][3]`.

Comment: I meant: the data as provided, would be for `int c[2][3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bracketed initializers are not arrays, and so cannot undergo decay to a pointer type.  And because `c` is an array of `int *`, each initializer needs to be of that type.  Nested initializers only work with actual arrays (not pointers) or structs.

What you can do however is use **compound literals** in the initializer which do have an array type.

```
int *c[2] = {(int []){1,2,3}, (int []){4,5,6}};
```

Comment: Thanks dbush, but why does compiler say the code is initializing `int *` with `int`? Does initializer have the type of `int`?

Comment: @mzoz Each value in the initializer list is an `int`, so that's what it attempts to assign to the elements of `c`.  The extra braces don't make the initializer an array.

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose array {1,2,3} would decay to pointer so the assignment be legit?

No.  `{1, 2, 3}` is not an array, and no decay applies to it.  It is an initializer suitable for initializing an array of three or more elements of arithmetic type, but you are trying to use it to initialize a pointer.  You could do something like this, instead:

```
static int x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
static int y[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
int *c[] = { x, y };
```

Or you could use compound literals to avoid declaring variables `x` and `y`, as another answer suggests.  In either of these cases, the initializer elements *are* arrays, and they *do* decay to pointers.

Comment: Thanks John, but why does compiler say the code is initializing `int *` with `int`? Does initializer have the type of `int`?

Comment: The first element of `{1, 2, 3}` does, and that's what the compiler is looking at.  The initializer for a scalar (including a pointer) can optionally be enclosed in `{}`.  GCC has diagnosed a small-picture item instead of recognizing and diagnosing the larger issue, and it is understandable that it does so.